# How do I add a scroll bar to a QMainWindow that has one central widget?

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

How can I add a scroll bar to a `QMainWindow`, when this `QMainWindow` contains just one central widget, which is bigger than the `QMainWindow` size?

So that the scroll bar can be used to see different parts of this central widget.

Answer (score 4):

Set the central widget of your `QMainWindow` to a `QScrollArea` and then set the widget of *that* new `QScrollArea` to the widget that was previously your central widget.

Remember to set the "widget resizable" property of QScrollArea to true.

Comment: Alright I just tried this .. works sort of .. the original widget is displaying, but the scrollbars don't appear even when the size of the originally central widget exceeds the size of the QMainWindow ..

Comment: @Ahmad try using setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy() and setVerticalScrollBarPolicy() on your QScrollArea.

Comment: @Casey I'm still no luck with it. I think the original central widget is not being set properly to trigger the scroll bar. Any idea?

Comment: Hello, ianmac45, thank you for your help. Could you please provide an example of what you are saying? I would appreciate that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the child widget would not render at all if it was a `QWidget` with a layout. It only worked after calling `setWidgetResizable(true)`.

```
auto mainWidget = new QWidget();
auto scrollArea = new QScrollArea();
scrollArea->setWidget(mainWidget);
scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
setCentralWidget(scrollArea);
resize(1470, 900);

QHBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout(mainWidget);
...
```